# OpenCV: Equivalent for Matlab's imhist(), with smart bins

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing

In Matlab, when you use the `imhist()` function with number of bins as a parameter, the bins are selected smartly, like the below call, returning a 40 bins histogram:

```
histogram = imhist(img, 40);
```

As for example, the intensity levels in the range [0, 25] visibly differ much more significantly than the intensity levels in range [230, 255], **the bins' ranges become greater as the intensity level grows**.

For example, in a histogram with 50 bins, I would **not** expect the values **0** and **5** to be in the same bin, but I would definitely expect **250** and **255** to be in the same bin.

Below is a diagram that shows it - you can see that in the lower intensity levels, the difference is much more visible:

[image: Diagram]

In OpenCV's `calcHist()`, all the bins have the same size, i.e. it does not take into account this fact about intensity levels.

- Is there an implementation of Matlab's `imhist()` in OpenCV?
- Is the Matlab implementation of `imhist()` available somewhere so we can try to "translate" it to OpenCV?

**EDIT:**

I've just checked it and found out the following details about how `imhist()` works:

With 5 histogram bins, it will be calculated for the following ranges:

```
1. [0, 31]    -> 32 colors
2. [32, 95]   -> 64 colors
3. [96, 159]  -> 64 colors
4. [160, 223] -> 64 colors
5. [224, 255] -> 32 colors
```

Another example with 10 bins:

```
1.  [0, 14]    -> 15 colors
2.  [15, 42]   -> 28 colors
3.  [43, 70]   -> 28 colors
4.  [71, 99]   -> 29 colors
5.  [100, 127] -> 28 colors
6.  [128, 155] -> 28 colors
7.  [156, 184] -> 29 colors
8.  [185, 212] -> 28 colors
9.  [213, 240] -> 28 colors
10. [241, 255] -> 15 colors
```

Strange... But this is how it works..

Looks like `imhist(im, num_bins)` works in the following way (pseudo code):

1. Calculate `x = 256 / (n-1)`
2. There are `n` bins. If we remove the first bin and the last bin, we have `(n-2)` bins. Let's let each of these bins have range of `x` intensity levels.
3. We assigned `x` to `(n-2)` bins, we still have one `x` left. Let's divide it half to the first bin and half to the last bin.

Example with 5 bins:

```
x = 256 / (5 - 1); % This results 64 and is going to be the size of the central bins
% Hence, now the size of the first and the second bin will be 32 each
```

Comment: Have you tried to print out the values of the histogram, both OpenCV and Matlab? They are probably equal, and what you are referring to is just visual perceptive trick.

Comment: calcHist allows you to specify variable bin sizes. http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html

Comment: @Miki of course I tried and the results where totally different. I made a deep research before I posted this question. I could "restore" the OpenCV results in Matlab by manually dividing the colors equally instead of using the smarter `imhist()`. The "smart" binning that `imhist()` does can help a lot with many tasks, e.g. classification

Comment: Can you post the two code snippets so I can easily reproduce your results? (I'm not saying you didn't research first, but it's better to exclude the obvious first :D)

Comment: Can you post the two code snippets so I can easily reproduce your results?